# Why did the Community User accept this answer?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

*I'm not sure if this question should be posted here or on [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Perhaps the mods can guide me best on this.*

---

I was going through the activity log of the [Community User](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) and noticed that it has [accepted many answers](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community?tab=activity&sort=accepts). I checked on Meta SE for any info on this behaviour, and [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158586/313042) explains that when the OP of either the question or the accepted answer has their account deleted, then the ownership of the accept transfers to the Community User.

However, in [this](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4488/3955) question both OP's are active, yet the accept belongs to the Community User (check the activity on Dec 14, 2016). Why is this? Does this have anything to do with the fact that the question was migrated from Music Practice and Theory SE?

Comment: "Community" isn't really a user, but rather an AUTOMATED PROCESS.  Woudn't "system" be a more appropriate noun?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most possibly, yes, it's because of the migration.

[This answer on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94096/241919) explains that

> The accepted answer will now persist when it is migrated.

---

Now, [that question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/4488/3955) was originally posted on Dec '16 before migrated. However, [the OP](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/users/4697/erick-verran) didn't have an account on this site **until Sep '17** (hover on the timestamp on "Member for"). Thus, when the question was migrated, it (and the acceptance) belonged to the Community user.

When the user finally created an account, the question now belonged to them, but not the acceptance (possibly until the OP unaccept and reaccept the answer)